# how to call a method after dispatch_after_seconds completes?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm looking to call a method after `dispatch_after_seconds` completes.

```
dispatch_after_seconds(0.1, ^{
   [self doTask];
}
```

how can i call a method so that it is executed after this is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dispatch_after_seconds(0.1, ^{
    [self doTask];
    [self doYourTask];
 }
```